# How to limit output text in XHTML?

Tags: xhtml

The function I tried.

```
  function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
    if (input.value > 100) input.value = 100;
  }
</script>
```

Below is the line of code I would like to limit the amount displayed.

```
   <rich:column>
       <h:outputText value="#{logresult.notes}" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
   </rich:column>
```

Edit:

Found a solution from another Helpful user.

Comment: [Is there a way to limit the amount of text in an output box using Javascript or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874298/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-amount-of-text-in-an-output-box-using-javascript-or)

Comment: You've already asked this. It was closed because it needs more details and clarity. You've just copy/pasted it without providing any of that.

Comment: What else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Since some people want to report my answers and block any help I can get. I will post the answer here.

```
Use CSS or a tag attribute: max-lines: 1;max-width: 200px;
```